# date.js failed to format "DateValue":"01/05/2014 12:00:00 ص" to correct format

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, datepicker, format

I am using date.js:
http://javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/source.php

I have get JSON data :

> "DateValue":"01/05/2014 12:00:00 ص"

I tried to use this JSON value (Just String) to bind on my textbox with Date Formating using following jQuery :

```
$("#" + id).val(formatDate(new Date(item.DateValue), "yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

But it shows **NaN/0NaN/0NaN** is there anything error with [date.js](http://javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/source.php)

Comment: What's with the Arabic character at the end?

Comment: that is I guess AM/PM notification

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove the funky characters, specifically the arabic character. Try using `replace()` and regex, so something like:

```
yourDateString.replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '');
```

This would remove all characters except a through z and 0 through 9, you may also need to keep slashes and colons though, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I guess the real problem with my String values which are binding the datetime value from database is using server datetime format. So, I opted to change the datetime zone to Standard US timezone that makes the system return valid AM/PM format and so there is no issue with date.js in formatting them.
Thanks for all suggestions!